# What does "navy-crowded seas" mean?

Tags: word-usage

From H. G. Wells:

> And looking across space with instruments, and ***intelligence***s such as
> we have scarcely dreamed of, they see, at its nearest distance only
> 35,000,000 of miles sunward of them, a morning star of hope, our own
> warmer planet, green with vegetation and grey with water, with a
> cloudy atmosphere eloquent of fertility, with glimpses through its
> drifting cloud wisps of broad stretches of populous country and
> narrow, ***navy-crowded*** seas.

1. Does "intelligenceS" mean intelligent beingS?
2. What does "navy-crowded seas" mean?

Comment: Wells is describing how the Earth would look to supposed Martians. They are **intelligent beings** who can see that our seas carry a **huge number of ships**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you.